# How to call two methods one by one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please have a look at this method. In this function response I am calling two functions `findConnectedUsersRelationship()` and `displayUsers(response.users)`.

The problem is `displayUsers(response.users)` method runs and gets result before `findConnectedUsersRelationship()`. My requirement is I need to run first `findConnectedUsersRelationship()` and second `displayUsers(response.users)`. Second method depends on first method.

```
function filterUsers(location, gender, youngAge, oldAge, interests){
        var userId = signedUserId;
        $.post(urlHolder.filter, {
            userId: userId,
            location: location,
            gender: gender,
            youngAge: youngAge,
            oldAge: oldAge,
            interests: interests
        }, function(response) {
            console.log('User response <<>>', response.users.length);
            var filteredUsers;
            findConnectedUsersRelationship();
            displayUsers(response.users);

        });
    }



// To find connected user relationship
var relationshipList = new Array;
function findConnectedUsersRelationship() {
    try {
        $.post(urlHolder.findConnectedUsersRelationship, {
            userId : signedUserId
        }, function(response) {
            //console.log('response downforanything: ', JSON.stringify(response));
            if (response) {
                for (var counter = 0; counter < response.users.length; counter++) {
                    relationshipList.push(response.users[counter].id);
                }
            } else {
                console.log('No connected users >>>> ');
            }
            //console.log('relationshipList.length',relationshipList);
            console.log('relationshipList length in auto complete *** ',relationshipList.length);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('findConnectedUsersRelationship Exception >>>', e);
    }

}
```

Comment: This can't be, because you call find.. before display. As alternative findConnect could call displayUsers.

Comment: You'll need to include what happens in findConnectedUsersRelationship() - most likely you have another $.post there.

Comment: how? the displayUsers(response.users) method gets the response of filterUsers function.

Comment: Is `findConnectedUsersRelationship` one of your functions? Can you show us the content?

Comment: yes, i added the code for findConnectedUsersRelationShip method. please have a look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.post` returns a `promise`.

You can use this to continue your code:

```
function filterUsers(location, gender, youngAge, oldAge, interests){
    $.post(url, { ... }, function(response) {
        findConnectedUsersRelationship().done(function() {
            displayUsers(response.users); 
        });
    });
}
```

and change your findConnectedUsersRelationship() to return the promise from its ajax function,so instead of:

```
function findConnectedUsersRelationship() {
    $.post(...
```

it becomes

```
function findConnectedUsersRelationship() {
    return $.post(...
```

Comment: Wouldn't this aproach trigger following errors whenever `catch` of `findConnectedUsersRelationship` kicks in, because there is no `promise` returned then?

Comment: findConnectedUsersRelationship().done(function() {
            displayUsers(response.users); 
        }); i add this but i am getting "done" is undefined.

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal you've not returned a promise from `findConnectedUsersRelationship`.

Comment: how to return a promise ? please tell me.

Comment: yes, i got it. i did not notice "return" in $post. Thank you very much.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks. I learnt a lot from you.

Comment: and I have an another question. please explain me about callback method in js.

Comment: Your best bet is to create a new question (add a link here if you like) - there might be adequate answers already on SO or someone else might be able to pick it up.